# Suppose $f$ (not necessarily continuous) is bounded on every neighborhood of $x$ in I. Show that $f$ is bounded on I (proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

Let $I = [a,b]$ and let $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a (not necessarily continuous) function with the property that $\forall x \in I$, the function $f$ is bounded on a neighborhood of $x$. Prove that $f$ is bounded on $I$.

I took a very roundabout approach to this. Let $B_{\delta_{x_{I}}}(x_i)$ be the open ball around each $x_i$. So,

$[a,b] \subset \bigcup_{i \in J} B_{\delta_{x_{i}}}(x_i)$

where $J$ is an index set. Since $[a,b]$ is compact, this cover has a finite sub cover.

$[a,b] \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{p} B_{\delta_{x_{i_{p}}}}(x_i)$

Now, suppose $|f(x)| \leq M_{i_{p}}$ on each $B_{\delta_{x_{i_{p}}}}(x_i)$. Then, take $M = max(M_{i_{p}})$. Therefore, $f(x)$ is bounded on $[a,b]$.

Does this work? I am not the best at the using the basic topology in real analysis, so I am curious about this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the title.   Can't be every neighborhood,  else it's trivial.

Comment: Apart from the misleading formulation in the title, it is correct (and a standard compactness argument).

Comment: I checked, the book, this is the actual question. But I am glad to know my argument works! Thanks!